# How do I "reset" remote repo to match my machine verbatim?

Tags: git, github

I'm not certain what is going on, but a file on the remote repo isn't updating properly It's showing a line with incorrect data. I've updated that line, moved that line around, added more lines, but yet the line is still incorrect on github.

I think what I want to do is blow away whatever is on github, and replace everything with exactly what is on my machine.

I don't know what commands to search.

Comment: rename the repo - create a new one with the same name - then push

Comment: you might look into `push --force-with-lease`

Comment: 1. Git stores *commits*, not files. (The commits then store files, but you say "a file in the remote repo": it doesn't have files at this level, it only has commits. You'd need to say "a file in a commit in the remote repo".) 2. Files stored inside commits literally *can't* be changed, so if some file inside some commit looks some way, it looks that way in *every copy of that commit*, in every repository that has that commit. Which commit (hash ID) are you looking at and how are you seeing this file?

Comment: These might seem picky, but being picky and precise is the crux of solving your problem.